# How to use binary search when the array has odd value?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I'm using `binarySearch` and it's worked well with arrays that has even index, but when the array has odd index (length) it's give wrong result.

What i'v done so fare:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) {

    int low = 0;
    int high = list.length - 1;
    while (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (key < list[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (key == list[mid])
            return mid;
        else
            low = mid + 1;

    }
    return - 1;
}
```

Input:

```
int[] arr1 = {5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 11, 50, 1, 3, 15, 121, 33, 16, 17, 18, 19};
int[] arr2 = {5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 11, 50, 1, 3, 15, 121, 33, 16, 17, 18};
```

Case:

```
System.out.println(binarySearch(arr1, 12));
System.out.println(binarySearch(arr2, 12));
```

OutPut:

```
-1
5
```

How i can get the right outPut in the both situation?

Comment: you need to sort arr1 and arr2 first

Comment: Binary search works on sorted data

Comment: As suggested in the comments
I suggest to have a look at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/24621/question-about-binary-search-please-help

Comment: @MuhannadA.Alhariri thanks that's was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search only works on sorted array

Solution : add Arrays.sort(list)

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) { 
    Arrays.sort(list);
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.length - 1;
    while (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (key < list[mid]) high = mid - 1;
        else if (key == list[mid]) return mid;
        else low = mid + 1;
    } return - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must sort the arrays before doing binary search operation.

In your question you are unable to search for the odd array length.

In java its very easy.

You can use the below code.

```html
import java.util.Arrays;
 
class BS 
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
        int[] arr1 = {5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 11, 50, 1, 3, 15, 121, 33, 16, 17, 18, 19};
 
        System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arr1 , '12'));
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess this task is more about implementing the search then learning docs.